# I need to run a python script from php

Tags: php, python, qiime

I have to design a interface using PHP for a software written in python. Currently this software is used from command line by passing input, mostly the input is a text file. There are series of steps and for every step a python script is called. Every step takes a text file as input and an generates an output text file in the folder decided by the user. I am using `system()` of php but I can't see the output but when I use the same command from command line it generates the output. Example of command :
`python /software/qiime-1.4.0-release/bin/check_id_map.py -m /home/qiime/sample/Fasting_Map.txt -o /home/qiime/sample/mapping_output -v`

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to call `system()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$script = 'software/qiime-1.4.0-release/bin/check_id_map.py -m /home/qiime/sample/Fasting_Map.txt -o /home/qiime/sample/mapping_output -v';
$a = exec($script);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not on windows, have you tried adding `2>&1` (redirect stderr to stdout) to the end of the command?

```
$output = system("python /software/qiime-1.4.0-release/bin/check_id_map.py -m /home/qiime/sample/Fasting_Map.txt -o /home/qiime/sample/mapping_output -v 2>&1", $exitcode);
```

Found from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#108713

Also the doc says that it

> Returns the **last line** of the command output on success, and FALSE on
>   failure.

So if you are trying to get multiple lines, you may need to redirect it to a file and read that in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I used the above trick and in this way I am getting something on the browser unlike before. But I am getting an error like this : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/software/qiime-1.4.0-release/bin/check_id_map.py", line 15, in 
    from qiime.util import parse_command_line_parameters, get_options_lookup
ImportError: No module named qiime.util

Comment: The code I am using is : $command='/software/python-2.7.1-release/bin/python /software/qiime-1.4.0-release/bin/check_id_map.py -m /home/qiime/sample/Fasting_Map.txt -o /home/qiime/sample/mapping_output -v 2>&1';
echo '<pre>';
$last_line = system($command);
echo $last_line

Comment: The coomand I am using works on the command line but not when I am using via PHP's system() function

Comment: I just fixed the problem. I needed to set the environment variable of php same as the environment variable of the linux terminal using PHP's putenv() function.

Comment: Hello user1564657, I am facing the same issue. Can you explain how did y set it? Thanks

Comment: @IGORALVES I believe they used: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.putenv.php

Comment: Hi justderb Thanks for your take your time to reply. Yes they used putenv() but I dont know how they did that. How to use this function. Do you have any idea? The documentation on php manual is not clear for me. Thanks

Comment: Looks like they simply did `env` in the console, then copypasta'd the output into `putenv()`.  That way their php system call mirrors their environment shell.  But really, I think you only need to put the `PATH` environment variable into `putenv()`.  (I don't think this is the right solution - but if it works for you, all the better!)

Answer (score 0):

instead of `system()` try surrounding the code in `ticks`...

It has a similar functionality but behaves a little differently in the way it returns the output..